# Unable to create Kafka Consumer using Kerberos Authentication System

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, kerberos, sasl

I am getting the below errors every time I try running Springboot JAR consumer which is giving me the below error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar!/:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/:2.


**Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:920) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:740) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:592) ~[jdk.security.auth:na]
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:747) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:672) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:670) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:670) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:581) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60) ~[confluent-encryption-vault-7.x.x-2.0.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/:na]
```

The command which I am using to run the code is :

```
java -jar -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/local/cida/tmp/jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb-uat.conf demo2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_v5.jar
```